# error C2823: a typedef template is illegal - function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, typedef

I want to define a function pointer type using templates. However, VS 2013 me that 'a typedef template is illegal'.
I am trying to write something like this:

```c++
template<typename SD>
typedef void(*FuncPtr)(void *object, SD *data);
```

Unfortunately this does not compile. I'd like to keep this thing short. Basically I need to define a type for a function pointer, whose argument is of a template class.

Comment: Add a language tag (like c++) so the right people can find this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since C++11, you can use the `using` keyword for an effect very much like typedef, and it allows templates:

```
template<typename SD>
using FuncPtr = void (*)(void*, SD*);
```

Before that, you had to separate the template from the typedef:

```
template<typename SD>
struct FuncPtr
{
     typedef void (*type)(void*, SD*);
};
```

(and the type name is `FuncPtr<U>::type` instead of just `FuncPtr<U>`)